# with unity5 I can't export into webGl

Tags: unity-game-engine

the program works on the unity editor with WebGl but when I hit build during building process unity stops and I have to close it from the task manager?
I've changed the player settings
for instance .Net 2.0 instead of .Net 2.0 subset 
stripping level into strip assemblies 
webgl memory size 512
and it didn't work, please any help

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem once when I have only 3 gb of ram and using WebGL Optimization Fastest setting. My ram is not enough so it use my HDD as a ram and it too slow, mostly crash unity

Don't know it the same problem